# How to get the index of item in array in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

in following object example:

```
{_id:Objectid('..........'), "food":[ {name: "apple", juice: 'max-full'}, {name: "watermelon", juice: 'semi-full'} ], {name: "orange", juice: 'max-full'}}
```

I use `{"food.juice":{"$regex":{"$regex":"max-"}` to select the food with `max-` in its juice

and then returns to me after projection

```
[{name: "apple", juice: 'max-full'}, {name: "orange", juice: 'max-full'}],
```

but I was wondering if I can have the index position of it in array too in the projection for the result to be or similar to

```
[{index: 0, name: "apple", juice: 'max-full'}, {index: 2, name: "orange", juice: 'max-full'}],
```